# Multiple vendor camera application

Tags: c#, inheritance, camera

Maybe a newbie question but I want to write an application that is going to interface to multiple vendor cameras. I want to write a Camera class which will be the base class so that in the runtime I can initialise it to a given vendor:

```
public class BaseClass
{
public void Connect(){}
public void Disconnect(){}
// common methods for cameras
}

public class VendorXCamera: Camera, VendorX_SDK_object
{}
public class VendorYCamera: Camera, VendorY_SDK_object
{}

BaseClass c_cam;
//choose Camera X or Y
c_cam = new VendorXCamera();
c_cam.Connect();
```

Now I know that I can't do it this way due to multiple inheritance limitation in C# and I won't get away with the interface. How should it be done the right way?

Comment: What do you mean by "and I won't get away with the interface"?

Comment: Actually the interface will be a part of solution like @maxwe said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exchangeability for cameras of different vendors can just be realized by implementing an interface ICamera. Note that you can inherit from arbitrarily many interfaces but only from one class in C#.

If you want to **share the implementation** of common methods for cameras you cannot do that within an interface but you have to create a base class which contains this methods. As some of the functionality of that base class might rely on the concrete vendors sdk you can declare some functions as *abstract* and implement them in the vendor specific child class. Therefore you should not not inherit from VendorX_SDK_object and VendorY_SDK_object but ruther make it an attribute of your child class.

```
public interface ICamera{
   void Connect();
   void Disconnect();
}

abstract class CameraBase:ICamera
{
   protected abstract void OpenStream();
   protected abstract void CloseStream();

   public void Connect(){
      Debug.WriteLine("connecting");
      OpenStream();
      Debug.WriteLine("connected");
   }
   public void Disconnect(){
      Debug.WriteLine("connecting");
      CloseStream();
      Debug.WriteLine("connected");
   }
}

class VendorXCamera: CameraBase
{
   private VendorX_SDK_object vendorx_sdk_object;

   protected override void OpenStream(){
      vendorx_sdk_object.OpenStream(..);
   }
   protected override void CloseStream(){
      vendorx_sdk_object.CloseStream(..);
   }

}

class VendorYCamera: CameraBase
{
   private VendorY_SDK_object vendory_sdk_object;

   protected override void OpenStream(){
      vendory_sdk_object.OpenStream(..);
   }
   protected override void CloseStream(){
      vendory_sdk_object.CloseStream(..);
   }

}
```